# Linux is making much more hard disk noise than Windows 7 on laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have 2 partitions on my Compaq laptop. Windows 7 is installed to one and Ubuntu 12.04 is installed to other using a usb stick installer.

What I noticed is whatever I do (opening a tab in browser, running a new program) is much slower and makes too much hard disk noise on Ubuntu. Also the boot time is longer on Ubuntu.

My Windows partition is ntfs and it is 100 GB.
Ubuntu partition is ext4 and 8 GB.

I have AMD Turion 64 cpu, 2.5 GB RAM and NVidia 6100 graphics card.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Adding the output of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       8.1G  5.7G  2.0G  75% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.2G  4.0K  1.2G   1% /dev
tmpfs           245M  1.4M  243M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.2G   13M  1.2G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Comment: 8 GB sounds small even if you had your home dir mounted in another partition. Can you tell us how much free space the 8 GB partition have? Did you installed anything that runs as a daemon and is not part of a default Ubuntu installation?

Comment: cant you add output of `df -h` please ?

Comment: Thank you, I added the output to the answer.
I didnt install anything. It is a fresh ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: this is a hardware issue.  On the inside of the hard disk, bits are packed more densely then on the outside of the hard disk, so the noise is different.  (And just by your description, *without hearing the noise* I can deduce that Ubuntu is on the *outside* of the disk)

Secondly, it's a really really small partition, so it gets the worst of the worst.

Thirdly, you've only got 2,5 GB or RAM.  Depending what you do on Ubuntu and which flavour you've installed and how you optimised your system, it might be swapping (adding to the noise)

**Conclusion:** If you only have that little space available for Ubuntu, why not buy a 16GB [**SLC USB stick**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) (**not** the MLC ones that you can find anywhere! Order an SLC!) install Ubuntu on there, set your `vm.swappiness` to 10, your `vm.max-readahead` to 2048, and your `vm.min-readahead` to 1024 and you'll have a much better Ubuntu experience without *any* noise... **;-)**

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer by Fabby in part. The slowness will really be an issue if you put something at the end part of a disc, especially if you put your data far from the swap partition (this last one doesn't seem to be your case). However, it will never make it louder. The noise have nothing to do with reads or writes, have to do with *seek* operations and with the spin of the disc.

Several hardware parts have noise management these days. HDs are no exception; if you run `sudo hdparm -M <device>` you can see if your hd have suport to manage noise and the settings you can change to make it faster or quieter.

Please, note that hdparm is a low level system tool, and if you can brick you hd playing with it. The command i show here is safe, but there are several things you can do here to destroy your data *and your hardware*, so please be carefull and as always, read the docs first.